# How long does it take for the image of an object falling into a black hole to disappear?

Tags: black-holes, redshift

From what I've read on other questions and answers, an outside observer cannot see an object fall into a black hole, but rather the image of the object will look like it is stuck on the surface of the event horizon, and then become reshifted until it disappears.

How much time would this redshift take and how much time would pass for the observer until the object is not visible anymore?

Comment: Not long, depending on how much light your object emits (or reflects). See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/21431/123208

Comment: The answer will depend on the sensitivity of your detector. As the sensitivity approaches infinity, the time to undetectability approaches infinity.